# Need relative paths from a batch script directory listing

Tags: shell, scripting, batch-file, windows-command-prompt

I have a simple batch script that recursively looks at all files and folders within the directory and writes out the file inventory to a text file. It currently looks like this:

```
dir /b/s > files.txt
```

The `/b` means don't give any extra info and `/s` makes it recursive within sub-folders. The sample output is:

```
C:\Users\mark\Desktop\site\site\Web
C:\Users\mark\Desktop\site\site\Web\Themes
C:\Users\mark\Desktop\site\site\Web\Themes\Sitev2
C:\Users\mark\Desktop\site\site\Web\Themes\Sitev2\images
C:\Users\mark\Desktop\site\site\Web\Themes\Sitev2\style
C:\Users\mark\Desktop\site\site\Web\Themes\Sitev2\images\site
C:\Users\mark\Desktop\site\site\Web\Themes\Sitev2\images\site\beta.gif
C:\Users\mark\Desktop\site\site\Web\Themes\Sitev2\style\site.css
C:\Users\mark\Desktop\site\site\Web\Themes\Sitev2\style\ie7.css
```

I'd like two things:

1. Only list out files in this listing rather than files and folders
2. I'd like the paths to be relative from where the batch script was called

E.g. I have the script in the `C:\Users\mark\Desktop\site\site\` folder so I don't want to see up to that point.

Is it possible to do those two things and if so, can anyone help with either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dir /b /s /a-d` will get you files only.  I think for relative paths you're going to need to do some more work than just a simple batch file, e.g. call some vbscript to (1) get the current directory, (2) open the text file, (3) do a search and replace on the text file, and (4) save the result back.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the extra flag! Worked perfectly. I agree about the path thing and I don't think I'll really be able to do it. I might look for some sort of batch script RegEx for a replace.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the [unxutils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/files/unxutils/current/UnxUtils.zip/download) suite, drop find.exe in your starting directory then launch it with something like:

```
./find.exe . -type f > result.txt
```

Just my 2cts.